# How can I get the full command name from shortcuts such as :syn, :synt?

Tags: vimscript

The commands `:sy`, `:syn`, `:synt`, and `:synta` all run the `:syntax` command. For a script I'd like to know which command the user typed on the commandline, for example:

```
get_full_command('syn')   " returns 'syntax'
```

The closest I got is:

```
getcompletion('syn', 'command')
```

But this returns the tab completion:

```
['SyntaxName', 'syncbind', 'syntax', 'syntime']
```

Which isn't really useful here, since I still don't know which command `:syn` runs.

How can I get the full command name from these shortcuts?

Comment: For user commands it's E464. For builtin commands, I believe, the first match in an internal table (ex_cmds.h) wins. So there wouldn't be a nice solution for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way shortcuts work is that `cmdidxs1` and `cmdidxs2` are defined in `ex_cmdidxs.h`, which contain a index to the actual command definition. It's not easy to re-implement this in Vim, as it depends on the order in which the commands are defined in `ex_cmds.h` (the reason `:s` is `:substitute` is because this occurs before any other command starting with `:s`).

The `find_ex_command()` function contains the logic to read these two cmdidx arrays, but that's not exposed anywhere in VimScript: it's only called when running a function and for `exists(':syn')`, which isn't much help here. So you'll need to copy those two lists and reïmplement the logic in VimScript.

But since [Vim 8.2.2468](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/038e09ee7645731de0296d255aabb17603276443) (Feb 2021) there is the `fullcommand()` function, which exposes this:

```
fullcommand('syn')     →  'syntax'
fullcommand('syntax')  →  'syntax'
fullcommand('s')       →  'substitute'
fullcommand(':%s')     →  'substitute'
```

As you can see, it removes ranges as well, so it's easier to use.

Comment: That was quick! MT is TCB. ;)